# Retrieve current suite's file name

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I use `protractor-angular-screenshot-reporter` and I need to retrieve file name of currently executed suite, so for example I have structure like this:

```
Tests.spec.js:

describe('describe1', function() {
   it('it1', function() {

   });

   it('it2', function() {

   });
});

describe('describe2', function() {

   it('it1', function() {

   });
});
```

Currently it builds final json like this:

```
   {  
      "description":"it1|describe1",
      "passed":true,
   },
   {  
      "description":"it2|describe1",
      "passed":true,
   },
   {  
      "description":"it1|describe2",
      "passed":true,
   },
```

but I need it to also return file name so I need something like this:`"description":"it1|describe2|Tests.spec.js"`

Anyone had similar problem?

Comment: A less elegant solution would be to create a variable `var thisfile = "hardcoded-file-name";` and pass that along. Because I'm not sure if `window.location.pathname` works with phantomjs etc.

Comment: I want to avoid setting it explicitly. Other people take care of writing tests I only make the reporter.